# Comma Usage After Locations

Tags: commas

What is the official rule when mentioning a city/ state in a sentence?

I always thought there was a requirement for a comma between the city and state, however is there also supposed to be a comma afterwards?

> Tim also enjoys football games, jumping on his motorcycle and being a
>   guide for the Fredrick, Alabama, restaurant scene.

I personally think it looks clunky, however I'm told that it is opinionated and that the above is correct.  Should the sentence be written like this?

> Tim also enjoys football games, jumping on his motorcycle and being a
>   guide for the Fredrick, Alabama restaurant scene.

Comment: The top is definitely incorrect. A state being mentioned does not warrant a comma unless the sentence structure requires it, and that in itself has nothing to do with the word.